# Plugin for sortable posts in grid

Tags: posts, plugin-recommendation, sort

I'm looking for a plugin that will emulate [this current php page](http://fairfieldflowers.biz/flower_matrix.php):

[image: Screenshot of flower grid]

1. Each flower to be a post with more info.
2. The dates to be sortable
3. Current blooming flowers to be featured in the widget sidebar (ok, this last one is probably a pipe dream).

Anyone have any clever ideas?  Maybe a cart system of some sort?

Comment: This is more something done with a theme than with a plugin. A plugin can add Custom Post Type support to hold the flowers and their information, but your theme will dictate how that information is displayed in the screen.

Comment: yeah i agree w/ @EAMann.  i think you are looking at rolling your own custom code here.  i think Types to setup some post types easily, and then customize your flower post type archive with a sorting script http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/